# Advice on thermal cameras

Tags: raspbian, camera, pi-zero-w

I'm thinking about getting a thermal camera for my Pi Zero. Anyone know what I should look for?  Can I use the Melexis MLX90640 32x24 or the Flir Lepton 80x64?

I just want to plug, simple and easy config (to an extent) and off it goes.

Comment: I've edited this a bit to keep within the bounds of [our policy regarding shopping recommendations](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  Basically: If something can be used is okay, how to use it is okay, but which one to buy is not okay.

Comment: Wasn't aware of that regulation. Thank you for sorting it out for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had experience with both modules, Melexis is pretty simple it just need *I2C* connection and the code you can easily find on GIT works fine and you'll be able to have a low res IR picture (at a good frame rate if you need). Lepton module (I used Lepton3 160x120 module but modules share the same h/w interface) is a little more complex since it needs both *I2C* and *SPI* connection. There are several repositories around with lots of infos but be carefull and check twice what they suggest because I found some (surprisingly Sparkfun' one) that reports a totally wrong wiring. I got some issues using Lepton3 with Raspberry Pi 0 W while it works fine with Raspberry Pi 3 B+. Melexis MLX90640 works fine with both boards.

Comment: of course if you need more specific info about this please ask.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on which is better, but web searching the first chip name with raspberry pi leads to this page: https://github.com/abood91/RPiMLX90640 that shows it working. Based on [another related search result](https://github.com/melexis/mlx90640-library/issues/5) the setup may or may not be what you would call easy. Similar could be done for the other one.